# How to fix Scrape key check failed on WordPress VPS?

Tags: themes, errors

I'm asking here because DigitalOcean support or forums have no idea what's going on.
I create a LAMP server and the I installed WordPress.
Everything was working ok, so I created a snapshot of the instance.
After I migrated the site to the new server, and then I receive I critical error from the PHP Code Widget plugin that I had on the original server. So, I removed the plugin, and now the site works.

Then I receive the error “Scrape key check failed. Please try again” when trying to save a PHP file with the WordPress Theme editor.

I know it's not ideal, but it should work nonetheless because then it means that there's a problem.

So, I disabled all the plugins, and I still get the same error.

I change the theme and I still getting the same error.

I have a cache plugin w3 total cache, so I disabled it too and deleted the cache, and I
continue with the same error.

So, then I decided to delete the VPS and create a new VPS, so tried to create another server with the image I created, and now without doing anything I receive the error “Scrape key check failed. Please try again” when trying to save a PHP file with the WordPress Theme editor. So, I don't get it, if it worked before, why I'm getting the error now when I haven't even transferred anything from the old server yet.

So, I created another VPS, but this time, I created another VPS using a clean LAMP image provided by DigitalOcean. Then I installed WordPress, and this is supposed to work, right? Wrong, I haven't done anything and every VPS I create from this point forward, I will receive the error “Scrape key check failed. Please try again” when trying to save a PHP file with the WordPress Theme editor.

Also, for this process, I've been using Chrome and Firefox in incognito mode. I switched computers. and I have even tried a different internet connection with a different computer to end with the same error.
The thing is now, I can't even create a brand new VPS without running into the issue.
Any ideas on how to fix this problem?
Thanks,

Comment: What version of WordPress is this? I've searched `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` for `scrape` and I find a very similar error message -- `Scrape nonce check failed. Please try again.` -- in `wp-includes/load.php`. It might have been called a "Scrape key" in the past -- the code checks the expected nonce against a transient called `scrape_key_*`.

Comment: This WordPress version 5.9.3

Comment: Here's an update: I figured out today that the error seems to only happen when the theme is active. For example, if I open the Theme editor with the active theme, and I save a PHP file, then I’ll receive the “Scrape key check failed. Please try again” error. However, while in the Theme editor, I select an inactive theme from the “Select theme to edit:” menu, then I can save PHP files from the other theme that is not active.
So, the problem is saving PHP files from the active theme. Any other ideas of what could be the problem?
Thanks,

Comment: There will always be a theme active. Is the issue only happening when a certain theme is activated? If so, contact the theme's support team for assistance.

Comment: The problem with that is that it happens with any theme.